Partial trace of single particle in 1D
Consider the wavefunction for a single particle in 1D discrete space $\psi(n)$ where $n\in [0, L]$.
How can I compute the reduced density matrix of the system in the subspace $n\in [0, l]$, $l<L$ ?
I am used to tracing out subsystems when there is an explicit tensor product structure, eg a system of qubits, but here I'm not sure how to approach the problem.

Why do you want to do that? I don't see how you can get a natural tensor product structure here. See the comments and answers in this MathOverflow thread to start with.

There's a natural correspondence between $L^2(0,L)$ and the Cartesian product of $L^2(0,l)$ with $L^2(l,L)$.  But the Cartesian product is not the same thing as the tensor product.

I think this is an interesting conceptual question, why such a hostile reaction ? This is not a HW problem. I eventually could solve it by mapping the state to a hard core boson chain, tracing out half of the chain, then going back to the spacial basis. (https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.09208)

Sorry--where are the "hostile" reactions? I--and I suppose also @MichaelSeifert -- just wanted to help and point out some (possibly) relevant stuff.

I don't know for sure why people think it might be homework or so, but if I had to guess it is because you did not motivate well enough why you want to do that. But again, I don't know. If I am not mistaken, I think you can vote to re-open and then again (parts of) the community have to decide.
